# How can distance and temperature be commensurable?

Tags: temperature, conventions, units, distance

I am sorry to intrude.  The discipline I know something about is metaphysics rather than physics itself.  And on Stack Exchange I spend my time on English Language and Usage.

I am struggling through Roger Penrose’s fascinating book *Fashion, Faith and Fantasy in the new physics of the universe* (Princeton 2016).  I am in the middle of his unravelling of what he calls the Big Bang paradox.

At 3.6 he provides the following “approximate” equivalents to Planck or absolute units.

“metre= $6.3\times10^{34}$
second=$1.9\times10^{43}$
gram.   =$4.7\times10^{4}$
kelvin.  =$7.1\times 10^{-33}$
C.         =$5.6\times10^{-122}$”

I can see how distance and time can be commensurable because of the speed of light.  But how can this commensurability apply between distance and (say) temperature?  I have tried the internet, but so far I have not found anything.  If the answer is that I have to go away and do a course on advanced physics - or maths, I should understand.  But if there is a simple explanation, I should be really grateful.

Comment: Probably https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units

Comment: Quantum mechanics can link energy to length via the wavelength of a particle with the De Broglie relation $\lambda = h / p$, and $p^2 / 2m = E$. The relation between distance and mass is given by the Schwarzschild radius $2MG/c^2$.

Comment: That helps.  I had forgotten about wavelength.  Of course!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roughly speaking, one can associate a temperature with the energy scale of each particle at that temperature, which for simple situations is 
$$E \sim k_B T.$$
Next, one can associate an energy scale with a frequency scale using the de Broglie relation,
$$E = \hbar \omega.$$
The physical interpretation of such a frequency scale for particles at temperature $T$ would be their typical frequency as waves. We don't need general relativity or even special relativity to make this statement, because the only constants that come in are $\hbar$ and $k_B$. Finally, a frequency/time scale can be associated with a distance scale using the speed of light, as you said.

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  I don’t pretend to understand it fully, of course, but it gives me a better idea.  I suppose I am (naively) wondering whether this degree of commensurability would allow us to infer from the total volume of the universe (if we were allowed to ignore for the sake of argument the problem that ‘simultaneous’ is problematic) its total notional mass?  Or vice versa?

Comment: @Tuffy Kind of, but you have to be careful. As you can see the comparisons only make sense if you specify what system you're talking about.

Comment: @Tuffy In the case of the size of the universe the answer is yes, as the vacuum energy of the universe (which gives a mass scale) can be used to determine its size. Indeed one can argue that the vacuum energy must be small precisely because we live in a macroscopic universe. It's a bit more complicated than just adding factors of $\hbar$, $c$, and $G$ though.

Comment: Yes, I see that.  But (forgive my asking this) what, in that case happens to so-called empty space?  Would that too be a function of the total mass/energy?

Comment: @Tuffy This is getting a bit far afield; if you want to ask more you can post a new question.